# How to write sql statement below in sqlalchemy expression?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

how do I write the below sql statement in `sqlalchemy` expression?

I'm using `sqlalchemy` with `PostgresSQL` and `arrays` is a `Column(ARRAY(Text))`.

The reason I need expression is because I need to put this into `set_` param of `insert.on_conflict_do_update()` which does not accept raw sql statement.

```sql
CASE WHEN table.arrays IS NULL OR NOT ARRAY[table.arrays] @> :arrays
            THEN array_cat(table.arrays, :arrays)
            ELSE table.arrays END
```